# OLEDB Jet 4.0 SQL Character Limit

Tags: sql, oledb, custom-fields

I am attempting to generate lines for an SDF (Space Delimited File). I am creating these lines from a DBASE IV DBF file using an OLEDB adapter with extended properties DBASEIV to get at the data. My data column output is 425 characters long after padding, I am placing this into a datagridview in VB.NET to display it.

However when I run my query, while it seems to execute correctly the resultant field is restricted to 256 characters. The longest individual field I am reading is 35 characters and I am returning a dataset with 2 fields, the barcode and the SDF line. As I understand it OLEDB Jet 4.0 tries to guess the type based on the first 8 rows, however as all rows are equal length for the data column (425 chars) I don't get why it is choosing the smaller field type. I assume it is because my field is a generated one using string concatenation. I have included the horrible SQL at the bottom of this question. So my question is how can I get the full 425 character output? Or is there a way I can specify the datatype for my own field as memo?

```
SELECT scan, 
RIGHT('0000000000000' + trim(cstr(scan)), 13) + 
LEFT(trim(cstr(name)) + '                                   ', 35) + 
LEFT(trim(cstr(name)) + '                ', 16) + 
'    ' + 
'             ' + 
'      ' + 
'1   ' + 
'0.00     ' + 
'0.00     ' + 
'1' + 
'0.00 ' + 
'0.01     ' + 
'0.00     ' + 
'F' + 
'2' + 
'0.00   ' + 
'0.00   ' + 
'   ' + 
'  ' + 
'  ' +
'SALS' + 
'    ' + 
'    ' +
LEFT(trim(cstr(plof)) + '             ', 13) + 
'             ' + 
'             ' + 
'0.00     ' + 
'0.00     ' + 
'0.00     ' + 
'F' + 
'T' + 
'001' + 
'    ' + 
'T' + 
'01' + 
'    ' + 
'        ' + 
'  ' + 
'    ' + 
'F' + 
'F' + 
'        ' + 
'        ' + 
'0   ' + 
'0.00     ' + 
'             ' + 
'0   ' + 
'0.00     ' + 
'0.00   ' + 
'0.00   ' + 
'0.00   ' + 
'1    ' + 
'1    ' + 
'1    ' + 
'0.00  ' + 
'0.00  ' + 
'0.00  ' + 
'0.00 ' + 
'0.00 ' + 
'0.00 ' + 
'                ' + 
'                ' + 
'  '
as STTEMPLINE
from salus where cstr(scan) in (select distinct cstr(scan) from nonscan)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue where data types are guessed based on data in the first few rows.

See this post...

[Load Excel sheet into DataTable but only the first 256 chars per cell are imported,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9800502/1246574)

Also, see this post for an explanation of how OLEDB deals with mixed data types...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/csharplanguage/thread/0404d003-5bfb-44f9-8e6b-aebdfce24875

Comment: Ah, I thought I had already covered this, every single one of my rows is the same length. Each row has only one column which is a mixture of imported data columns and defaults as can be seen from the code, the longest input column is only 35 characters but all result table rows are 425 characters, so reading every row still would not help because all rows are over the limit it must do something different for resultant columns generated from a query rather than direct imports. Basically I am trying to create a fixed length record file from a DBF file.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I read your question quickly and not thoroughly enough.  Do you perhaps ever have any null, or whitespace-only values for name or scan?  That's the only thing I could think of that might affect this.  Maybe some empty rows at the very beginning?  Anyways, if it were me, I'd just select the name and scan values, and do all this string concatenation in VB or C# code, instead of in the select statement.  That should be fairly straight-forward to manipulate the data after it's loaded by OLEDB, instead of during the query.

Comment: hmmm, nope, no whitespace, we pad SCAN to 13 digits with 0's so SCAN is always 0000000000000 - 9999999999999. The reason I want to do this in SQL is that I wrote a tool which allows me to operate on pretty much any datafile by providing a connection string and a query. I need to do something like this very nearly every time we get a new customer but the input files are always different, being able to just do a quick SQL to create my data files is so much better than having to write a new program each time, so far we have over 100 unnecessary programs.

Comment: The problem is that every supplier has its own data file format missing a lot of information but each file is missing different info. With my tool it is quick to just copy a complete list of defaults in then replace only the fields for which the supplier gives data with field names resulting in importable data in around 10 minutes at worst! (After cleaning up the files a bit of course, removing nonsense etc.) This means that my tool can even be used by the support department without needing to resort to the developers.

Comment: at the moment I got it to work by just splitting it down the middle into two output fields, copying them from the datagrid into notepad++ and replacing all tab characters with another ','. But this question remains important because the file I am outputting is the main way we get data changes into the system from many sources and my tool would allow us to script the process to create what we need easily from almost any datasource needing only a single standard compiled program for all of our clients, simplifying deployment, tweaks, on the fly imports etc.

Comment: Check out these links for how to use a schema.ini file with your DBase connection...  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326548   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15634/discussion-between-jim-and-feldoh)